# Win UI3 binding to AutoSuggestBox in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, winui-3, xbind

I am invoking the QuerySubmitted and SuggestionChosen command of the AutoSuggestBox control in WinUi 3. The commands binds to ICommand in the view model.

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="Control2" PlaceholderText="Type a control name"
        TextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged" QueryIcon="Find" QuerySubmitted="SearchBox_QuerySubmitted"
        SuggestionChosen="SearchBox_SuggestionChosen" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

following code need to be converted to a DelegateCommand in view model.

```
  public void SearchBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
  {
  
      if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null )
      {

      }
      else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.QueryText))
      {

      }
  }
```

Here is the question on how to do it in UWP.
[UWP Binding to AutoSuggestBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620388/uwp-binding-to-autosuggestbox-in-mvvm)

But the question and the top answer are 8 years old, is there a new(better)way to implement this in WinUi 3? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please install following nuget package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed

then you can use Interaction and bind your method (from viewmodel) in your xaml

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="Control2" PlaceholderText="Type a control name"
        TextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged" QueryIcon="Find" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted">
                <ic:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                    <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchBox_QuerySubmitted}" />
                </ic:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SuggestionChosen">
                <ic:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                    <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchBox_SuggestionChosen}" />
                </ic:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

and csharp:

```
public void SearchBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{

}

public void SearchBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{

}
```